# errors in latex algorithm formatting Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item

Tags: algorithm2e, algorithmicx, algorithmic

I am trying to write an algorithm and I receive the following errors

```
Missing = inserted for \ifnum. \end{algorithmic}


Command \algorithmic already defined. }
Missing = inserted for \ifnum. \end{algorithmic}

Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. 
...methodTrace.Method.Owner.DeveloperGold==E}

Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \ENDWHILE

Underfull \vbox (badness 1270) has occurred while \output is active []
```

---

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

% The preceding line is only needed to identify funding in the first 
%footnote. If that is unneeded, please comment it out.

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{0.1cm}

\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}


\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Calculate $y = x^n$}
\begin{algorithmic} 

\FORALL{methodTrace in methodTraceList} 
\IF{methodTrace.Method.Owner.DeveloperGold==T}    methodTrace.Prediction=E 
\ELSIF{methodTrace.Method.Owner.DeveloperGold==N} methodTrace.Prediction=N 
\ELSIF{methodTrace.Method.Owner.DeveloperGold==E} methodTrace.Prediction=E  
\ENDIF
\ENDFOR
\WHILE{$OldPredictions \neq NewPredictions$}
    \FORALL{methodTrace in methodTraceList} 
        \IF{ \NOT methodtrace.Method.Callees.isEmpty() \AND  
        \NOT methodtrace.Method.Callers.isEmpty() 
        \AND methodtrace.Method.Callees.AllTs(methodtrace.Requirement, methodtraces2HashMap) 
        \AND methodtrace.Method.Callers.AllTs(methodtrace.Requirement, methodtraces2HashMap)
        } methodTrace.Prediction=E 
    \ENDFOR 
\ENDWHILE
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a missing `\ENDIF` for the last `\IF` and each `\IF-\ELSIF` requires a `\STATE`. Also, `if-elsif-elsif-end` should be `if-elsif-else-end`.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

% The preceding line is only needed to identify funding in the first 
%footnote. If that is unneeded, please comment it out.

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{0.1cm}

\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}


\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Calculate $y = x^n$}
\begin{algorithmic}
\FORALL {methodTrace in methodTraceList}  
    \IF {methodTrace.Method.Owner.DeveloperGold==T}  \STATE methodTrace.Prediction=E
    \ELSIF {methodTrace.Method.Owner.DeveloperGold==N} \STATE methodTrace.Prediction=N 
    \ELSIF {methodTrace.Method.Owner.DeveloperGold==E} \STATE methodTrace.Prediction=E  
    \ENDIF
\ENDFOR
\WHILE {$OldPredictions \neq NewPredictions$}    
    \FORALL{methodTrace in methodTraceList}   
        \IF {\NOT methodtrace.Method.Callees.isEmpty() \AND  
            \NOT methodtrace.Method.Callers.isEmpty() 
            \AND methodtrace.Method.Callees.AllTs(methodtrace.Requirement, methodtraces2HashMap) 
            \AND methodtrace.Method.Callers.AllTs(methodtrace.Requirement, methodtraces2HashMap)
            } \STATE methodTrace.Prediction=E
        \ENDIF 
    \ENDFOR 
\ENDWHILE
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

> [image]